# Android actionbar sherlok doesn't show divider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the sherlok-actionbar and trying to apply a divider between the action buttons.
I have th style but the dividers are not visible, why?

```
<style name="Theme.SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="abBackground">@drawable/actionbar_gradient</item>
    <item name="abIcon">@drawable/logo</item>       
    <item name="abDivider">@drawable/ab_divider</item>
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock v3.5 was updated to include the sources from Ice Cream Sandwich for all action-item related views and classes. This means that the rules for placing a divider between two action items follows the same rules as it would on ICS.

A divider would only be shown between the following:

- Text-only followed by text-only
- Icon-only followed by text-only
- Text and icon followed by text-only

If you want to override this behavior (on pre-3.0 only) make the following change to `ActionItemView.java`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't expect for a better answer!

Comment: Why do the Google Android apps show dividers between icons then? see YouTube app

Comment: Because they use their own library.

Comment: This is not applicable to 4.0.2 . How can I accomplish the same effect there?

Comment: How to change ActionItemView.java? Where to find it? How to edit it?

Comment: Since `ActionBarSherlock v4.1.0`, the source needing to be modified is within `com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java`, search for `needsDividerBefore` and apply the suggested patch/fix

Comment: hello, I tried the solution given here and updated the ActionMenuItemView.java file, but it did not worked for me. Dividers are only shown if text are followed by icon. Please help. What should I do.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is to add a view next to the actionbar item that will look like the separator (works on all Android versions)

```
<item
    android:actionViewClass="com.example.ActionSeparatorView"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@null"/>
```

and the ActionSeparatorView is a simple extension of the ImageView with the drawable you want to show as a separator

```
public class ActionSeparatorView extends ImageView {
public ActionSeparatorView (Context context) {
    super(context);
    setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.separator));
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. only love for you. (Y)

Comment: I tried using this approach, separator appears however it increases lot of space between menu items.