# ActionBar MenuItem Divider

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to show Divider between the Menu Items in ActionBar for HoneyComb+.

Some post says that the Divider will be shown only when the menu items has android:showAsAction="withText".

I want to show only the Icon not the Text.

I successfully shown Divider for Pre-HoneyComb by implementing a Action Bar Compatibility.

I dont want to use ActionBarSherlock as given in this post [Android actionbar sherlok doesn't show divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274259/android-actionbar-sherlok-doesnt-show-divider) because it will be time to change from Action Bar Compatibility to ActionBarSherlock in my all Projects.

When i saw the Android Source i found that Divider will be show only when it has text as shown below (from ActionMenuItemView)

```
public boolean needsDividerBefore() {
    return hasText() && mItemData.getIcon() == null;
}

public boolean needsDividerAfter() {
    return hasText();
}
```

Is there a way that I can give my Implementation for ActionMenuItemView for ActionBar where needsDividerBefore() will always give true

Comment: Maybe you could use a button with icon of divider but without any action?

Comment: add dynamic vertical view there. it will work for sure

Comment: I want to use the action Bar implementation of HoneyComb+. I can replace the ActionBar with Action Bar Compatibility which i am going with Pre-HoneyComb. But i don't want to use that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an answer by myself with help of http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html However, this does not completely solve my problem. It adds a divider for Title, and also one for the home Icon. There are also left and right separators. That too is adjustable.

I added android:selectableItemBackground to my theme.

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
```

action_bar_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_compat_separator"></item>

    <item android:left="1dp" android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_compat_item"></item>

</layer-list>
```

actionbar_compat_separator - is my seperator drawable

and actionbar_compat_item is my selector for action bar item.

**EDITED**

I have found a better solution to my problem. It works well.

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton</item> to my Theme

<style name="ActionButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can override existing theme with custom styles, for e.g.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/action_bar_divider</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update: This doesn't seem to work for Android 5 Lollipop and above:

---

This is the best way I found. Just add a group with a dummy item to your menu:

**menu.xml**

```
<group>
    <!--dummy item to get a nice separator-->
    <item
        android:title=""
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:enabled="false" />
</group>

<item android:id="@+id/action_example"
    ...
```

The dummy item has an empty title so it appears invisible, and it's disabled so it can't be clicked.