# Title Bar like that of Youtube app

Tags: android, android-layout, titlebar

[image]

I want this type of custom title bar
But can anyone tell me what the portion marked with red is made of? I mean are they tabs or image buttons or something else? Please don't give me links on how to apply a custom title bar, I already know it. But I don't know what the red-marked portion is (tabs or image buttons etc) And how can I have that vertical line between Search and Make Video option (in the portion that's marked red) I'm using Gingerbread.

I tried using search engines but how can I search when I don't know the name of the thing I want to search :s

Comment: Essentially, it's a MenuItem on the ActionBar with custom styled divider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called `ActionBar Action Items`. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html\

As for dividers, take a look at: [ActionBar MenuItem Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338867/actionbar-menuitem-divider)

Comment: also, it's not "custom", it's standard any app can add this.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use ActionBarSherlock.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

This is for add actionbar in devices android <3.x.