# Dropdown menu items with custom views Android showAsAction never

Tags: android, performance, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am looking for the right way to implement dropdown menu with custom menu items. Default menu provided by `Action Bar` or `Toolbar` suits great, I also need "three dots" in the right top corner of the screen. But the problem is that I can specify custom layout for menu item only if it is visible directly on action bar.
But in my case I need custom views for dropdown items, for example one item is divide other items has also different views that can be specified for each item, not for all (like using style generators).
Here is an example I have found here on stackoverflow, I need similar menu, as you can see here there are differen types of items checkboxes simple items......
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ohry.png]

I need at least something like trick with `ListView` or `RecyclerView` when depending on item type inflating different layout.

I am asking about this, because maybe it is possible to implement using default menu or if it isn't get advice what is the most efficient and right way to implement this without causing performance problems and not reinventing the wheel.

I would appreciate any help or advice.
Thank you.

Comment: use custom drop down spinner with Action Bar

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar can I use it with "three dots" ? Can you provide an example plese ?

Comment: yes you can also use that like option menu but its not showing like your image. so if you want same as that image then you have to use custom adapter. or using menu(three dots!!) here is answers please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/15851920/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11338867/1168654