# How to show ActionBar MenuItem Divider in AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid Theme

Tags: java, android

I want show divider for only beginning of menu item in particular fragment. I tried some code in my theme but its not shown.

My code here:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/s</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/myDrawerBackground</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Please anyone help to fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11445488/1930006