# Add separator in menu

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu and I want to have a separator between items, like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

PS
I create the menu in xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.gl.rest.ResultsActivity">


<item
android:id="@+id/action_viewlog"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="View"
app:showAsAction="never"
/>

<item
android:id="@+id/action_shareallresults"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="Share"
app:showAsAction="never"
/>

<item
android:id="@+id/action_qhelp"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="Help"
app:showAsAction="never"
/>
```

Comment: You should put at least from where that menu comes from and how do you populate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionBar MenuItem Divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338867/actionbar-menuitem-divider)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11445488/4848308

Comment: post your menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to create groups with **unique IDs** and the separator will apear between them. Something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/item_1" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/item_2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: I tried this. I don't get any lines. Instead, items appear as radiobuttons.