# ActionbarSherlock Action Item divider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How can I show a divider in Action Bar item?

I want: | ACTION_1 | ACTION_2

I think that I need to modify the ActionMenuItemView background png but I'm not sure.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried modifying the `ActionMenuItemView` background `.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Jake in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274259/android-actionbar-sherlok-doesnt-show-divider), the divider is only shown when one of the following types of `ActionButton`s are used:

> - Text-only followed by text-only
> - Icon-only followed by text-only
> - Text and icon followed by text-only

If you wish to have it always display, refer to the answer and modify the `ActionItemView.java` source file within the ActionBarSherlock Library Project. Also see my comment on that answer to retrieve the location of the source file in question.

Other than that, if you would also wish to style that divider, refer to this other [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449265/android-actionbar-actionitem-and-divider).