# ActionBar Divider Styling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image: foursquare printscreen]

I have two questions. Before detailing these questions, I want to add I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`.

The first question would be that I am having issues with adding a divider between `ActionItems` in my `ActionBar`. In the printscreen, there are 3 dividers, for instance the first one is between the **back button** and **Check In**.

I customized my ActionBar using the style below. However, the drawable called `small_detail_divider` does not show up. I also tried adding this divider programmatically, using the `setBackgroundSplitDrawable()`. That did not help either. What should I do to add divider between those `ActionItem`s?

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>       
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/top_panel_background</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/application_logo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/application_logo</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>
</style>
```

Another question would be: I want to add action items in the same manner as they are added within the printscreen. When I add the action items, they are always added to the right of the `ActionBar`. How can I add an action item to the left of the `ActionBar` such as the Back Button in the printscreen? Any suggestion would help.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the attribute you are looking for is:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>
    ....
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Just to give you some more info.

The split ActionBar should be set with:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBarSplit</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBarSplit</item>
    ...
```

Then provide your custom style for the split action bar..

Thrid question: Adding in order:

When you add the menu item pragmatically use: [Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

`menu.add (0, R.id.menu_new_ab_item, 0, "Item");`

The order determines how you order your menu items.

You can be more specific in your menu.xml files `android:orderInCategory="1..n"` can be any int. I normally start at 10 or so, so I can inflate items in-front of the standard items.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I tried the xml containing divider you wrote, it did not work also. What is wrong with it?

Comment: My appologies try `actionBarDivider` updated answer take note how its in the theme not the style.. inconsistant I know..

Comment: Thank you, I have also a new question. Please could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460931/actionbarsherlock-tab-navigation-with-viewpager-and-multifragments

Comment: Also to give an idea on what kind of drawable the `small_detail_divider` should be, look into ActionBarSherlock's `res\drawable-*` folders, at the `abs__list_divider_holo_dark.9.png` 9Patch PNG for inspiration

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins Mind take a look on my questions regarding actionBar menuItem's divider?