# Split line on Android ActionBar

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar, line, android-styles

[image: Split line sample image]

You can see a split line (inside red circle) in `ActionBar` which separate each icons in the `ActionBar`. 
How can I implement this kind of line in my android `ActionBar`?
And I searched lot about split line in `ActionBar` but I didn't find any answer so if you know tell me the term used for this kind of line in `ActionBar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar Divider Styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449265/actionbar-divider-styling)

Answer (score 0):

To make a split line you cand use:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/verticalline"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:src="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />
```

Or you can use: android:actionBarDivider
Defines a drawable resource for the divider between action items. (Added in API level 14.)

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Cheers,