# how to show divider between icon and title in actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBar. I want to add splitter between icon and title: For example like here:
[image: screenshot]

Nothing from these answers helped me:
[Android actionbar sherlok doesn't show divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274259/android-actionbar-sherlok-doesnt-show-divider)
[ActionBar Divider Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449265/actionbar-divider-styling)
[ActionBar MenuItem Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338867/actionbar-menuitem-divider)

I've tried to apply style to ActionBar but Eclipse shows this:

> android:showDividers requires API level 11 (current min is 9)

What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar MenuItem Divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338867/actionbar-menuitem-divider)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to add divider logo. If later you want it is not displayed click, just make its selector and put a logo without the divider for statepressed but with the same dimensions.