# android actionbar sherlock dividers

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use Actionbar Sherlock in my android app
How can I make this style dividers between icons in the layout?
I tried to make it by actionBarDivider, but it separates only between the icon and text. And it does not display by the full height actionbar

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r48oq85mx8z68ug/actionbar.png

my style file

```
 <style name="Theme.amoCrm" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.amoCrm.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.amoCrm.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>  

    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_divider_px</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_divider_px</item>
    <item name="dividerVertical">@drawable/actionbar_divider_px</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.amoCrm.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar</item>

    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>

    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>

    <item name="divider">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>

    <item name="itemPadding">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:itemPadding">15dp</item>
</style>
```

my activity

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Add")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_add_icon)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_search_icon) 
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}
```

as a result I get like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5w9vnbqts03t9p/actionbar_2.png

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274259/android-actionbar-sherlok-doesnt-show-divider

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue