# Missing separator in android Option Menu

Tags: android-menu

i am using option menu in my application. Here i need to display separator between tow menu icons. [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12247198/1318946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this, [Android actionbar sherlok doesn't show divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274259/android-actionbar-sherlok-doesnt-show-divider).

It talks about the divider and conditions for it working.